# Why is hover for input triggered on corresponding label in CSS?

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-selectors, webkit

Am I missing something, or the behavior of this example — http://dabblet.com/result/gist/1716833 — is rather strange in Webkits/Fx?

There is an input with label and the following selector:

```
input:hover + .target {
    background: red;
}
```

And this style is triggered when you hover the `label` attached to the `input`, not only the `input` itself. Even more: there is a difference between the `label` with `for` and `input` wrapped in a `label`  — if you'd hover the `input` at first and then move the cursor straight to the `.target` — the strange hover won't trigger in wrapped version.

And this is only reproduces in Firefox and Safari/Chrome, but in Opera it's ok.

So, the questions is: if this issue is described somewhere in specs? I couldn't find any appropriate place that describes it and tells what behavior is right.

Comment: According to http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9, "When a LABEL element receives focus, it passes the focus on to its associated control."

Comment: Yes, but a [focus](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#focus) in HTML is a one thing, and the pseudo-classes in CSS are another, there can't be any parallels between those areas. The similar case had been described in CSS4 as a draft: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#idref-combinators — but I don't think, that this must work as it is now do in Fx and webkits.

Comment: @kizu: `:focus` is a CSS pseudo-class, too. You're right in that label focus has nothing to do with the issue here, but it's just something I thought of pointing out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is in the HTML spec now; it wasn't until the [October 2012 WD](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/links.html#selector-hover) that it was added to W3C HTML5 (emphasis mine):

> The `:hover` pseudo-class is defined to match an element "while the user *designates* an element with a pointing device". For the purposes of defining the `:hover` pseudo-class only, an HTML user agent must consider an element as being one that the user *designates* if it is:
>
> - An element that the user indicates using a pointing device.
> - An element that has a descendant that the user indicates using a pointing device.
> - **An element that is the labeled control of a `label` element that is currently matching :hover.**

Identical text appears in the [living spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage).

---

I discovered this very behavior a few years ago on the previous design of my site's contact form, where `label:hover` also triggers `:hover` on any form input element that is either its descendant or referenced by its `for` attribute.

This behavior was actually added to a recent build of Gecko (Firefox's layout engine) in [this bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656379) along with [this (rather short) mailing list thread](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2011May/0130.html), and it was implemented in WebKit [many years back](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3244). As you note, the behavior doesn't reproduce in Opera; it looks like Opera Software and Microsoft didn't get the memo.

All I can find in the spec that *could* relate to this behavior somehow is [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act), but I don't know for sure (italicized note by me):

> - The `:hover` pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it. For example, a visual user agent could apply this pseudo-class when the cursor (mouse pointer) hovers over a box generated by the element.
>
> *[...]*
>
> Selectors doesn't define if the parent of an element that is ‘`:active`’ or ‘`:hover`’ is also in that state. *[It does not appear to define the same for the child of an element either.]*
>
> > **Note:** If the ‘`:hover`’ state applies to an element because its child is designated by a pointing device, then it's possible for ‘`:hover`’ to apply to an element that is not underneath the pointing device.

But what I *can* conclude is that this behavior is by design in at least Gecko and WebKit.

---

Regarding what you state here:

> Even more: there is a difference between the `label` with `for` and `input` wrapped in a `label` — if you'd hover the `input` at first and then move the cursor straight to the `.target` — the strange hover won't trigger in wrapped version.

Given the above behavior, the only possibility left here is that you've simply been bitten by the cascade.

Basically, this rule:

```
/* 1 type, 1 pseudo-class, 1 class -> specificity = (0, 2, 1) */
input:hover + .target {
    background: red;
}
```

Is more specific than this rule:

```
/* 1 class, 1 pseudo-class         -> specificity = (0, 2, 0) */
.target:hover {
    background: lime;
}
```

So in applicable browsers, the `label.target` by your first checkbox will always be red on hover, because the more specific rule always takes precedence. The second checkbox is followed by a `span.target`, so none of this behavior applies; only the second rule can take effect while the cursor is over the `span.target`.

Comment: «So in applicable browsers, the label.target will always be red on hover, because the more specific rule always takes precedence» — There is one thing. Go to the example, to the second block, hover the checkbox and then go straight to the right: when you'll hover the `.target` it would be lime! However, links to mailing lists and bugs are really nice! In resume: there are no signs of this behavior in specs, this is only the browsers' decision. Sad that there were no drafts in w3 from them to “legalize” it.

Comment: @kizu: That happens because in your second block, it's a `span.target`, not a `label.target`. I edited my answer to explain this. As for the specifications... maybe I'll pester the CSS working group about it one day.

Comment: I understood that, I'm wondering about this behavior: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R94O9H1sZBY — why the block becomes green after it's hovered from the input, but not directly? Due to specificity it must be always red, but still.

Comment: @kizu: Oh... I have no idea about that. Even when I look at it in Firebug (enabling `:hover` styles), it doesn't seem to apply the styles consistently.