# css hover only work on firefox

Tags: html, css, hover, css-selectors

css hover only work on firefox, dont work on chrome and ie, this is my code

**html**

```
<li><input type="checkbox" class="p4" name="i305" id="check305" /><label for="check305"><span></span></label></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" class="p4" name="i306" id="check306" /><label for="check306"><span></span></label></li>          
<li><input type="checkbox" class="p4" name="i307" id="check307" /><label for="check307"><span></span></label></li>
```

**css**

```
input.p4[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
input.p4[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-6px 0 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(../images/check1.png) 1px top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}
input.p4[type="checkbox"]:hover + label span {
    background:url(../images/check1.png) -21px top no-repeat;
}
input.p4[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background:url(../images/check1.png) -43px top no-repeat;
}
```

Can anybody please help me to make function the hover css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:hover` should be applied to the label, not the checkbox (*since that is not visible so it cannot be hovered..*)

```
input.p4[type="checkbox"] + label:hover span {
    background:url(../images/check1.png) -21px top no-repeat;
}
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rkbeK/

---

*(see [Why is hover for input triggered on corresponding label in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098581/why-is-hover-for-input-triggered-on-corresponding-label-in-css) for more info)*